# How much Google Drive API quota will be consumed to download large files?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-drive-api

I use Google Drive API to create direct download link for my files but I don't know how much quota will be consumed If a user download one large file. Does one download consume one quota or is there something else happening?

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer?

In my test, I could obtain the following results.

1. When a file is downloaded by one request using Drive API, one quota is used.
2. When a file is downloaded by multiple requests with [the partial download](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#partial_download) using Drive API, the quotas of the number of requests are used.

   - For example, when a large file is downloaded by splitting 2 parts, 2 quotas are used.

It seems that in this case, the use of quotas are related to the number of requests, and not related to the file size. You can check the current quotas of Drive API at [Quotas of Google Drive API of API&Service](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas) in Google Cloud Platform.